# how to initialise the pushnotification

Tags: angular, push-notification, ionic2

i am just following this https://github.com/phonegap/phonegap-plugin-push/blob/master/docs/TYPESCRIPT.md guidline

in my app.components.ts file

```
import { Push, PushToken } from '@ionic/cloud-angular';

constructor(platform: Platform) {
    platform.ready().then(() => {
      // Okay, so the platform is ready and our plugins are available.
      // Here you can do any higher level native things you might need.
      StatusBar.styleDefault();
      Splashscreen.hide();
    });

    var push = PushNotification.init({
        android: {
            senderID: '1234XXX9' //GCM project number
        },
        ios: {
            alert: 'true',
            badge: true,
            sound: 'false'
        },
        windows: {}
    });
    push.on('registration', (data) => {
        console.log(data.registrationId);
    });

    push.on('notification', (data) => {
        console.log(data.message);
        console.log(data.title);
        console.log(data.count);
        console.log(data.sound);
        console.log(data.image);
        console.log(data.additionalData);
    });

    push.on('error', (e) => {
        console.log(e.message);
    });
  }
```

i am getting error on this line  `var push = Push.init({`

when i give ionic build android i am getting error error on the above line.

If i am missing any points please let me know.

errors

```
[10:18:05]  typescript: src/app/app.component.ts, line: 24 
            Cannot find name 'PushNotification'. 

      L24:      var push = PushNotification.init({
      L25:          android: {

[10:18:05]  transpile failed 
[10:18:05]  ionic-app-script task: "build" 
[10:18:05]  Error: Error
```

Comment: what is the error message?

Comment: check my updated question

Answer (score 1):

Push you are using is a cloud service from Ionic.

TO use ionic cloud plugins,you have to setup your project with ionic cloud.
[Setup steps here](http://docs.ionic.io/setup.html)

Check the Push specific docs [here](http://docs.ionic.io/services/push/).
You should inject it instead of trying global variable.

```
constructor(platform: Platform, private push:Push) {
    platform.ready().then(() => {
      // Okay, so the platform is ready and our plugins are available.
      // Here you can do any higher level native things you might need.
    this.push.register().then((t: PushToken) => {
        return this.push.saveToken(t);
    }).then((t: PushToken) => {
       console.log('Token saved:', t.token);
    });
      StatusBar.styleDefault();
      Splashscreen.hide();
    });
```

Comment: as you said i did but still facing the same issue i have installed ionic@cloud and deployed in ionic.io and i have created GCM project number and server API key but not able to solve the issue

Comment: PushNotification object is used if you are using the plugin directly.. You will have to use through Push class provided by Ionic

Comment: actually i have tried both but still i am not able to solve the error as you can see in my question i am faceing that error

Comment: can you add app.module.ts to the question?

Comment: can you update your answer with the steps for doing pushnotification i am still not able to build a project

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/133623/discussion-between-mohan-gopi-and-suraj).